# Call methods on looped images

Tags: silverstripe

I have followed along with the tutorial on creating a simple image gallery using UploadField (extending Image with a DataExtension). I was using the BulkImageUploader extension for my gallery, but thought I would attempt to use native SS functionality. I am able to loop through the GalleryImages in my template and gain access to $URL, $Title, etc but how would I call methods I have created in an ImageExtension on the each looped Image or Image template methods on each?

For example:

```
$Image.setWidth(80)
```

does not work. Nor does

```
$File.setWidth(80).
```

I would like the ability for all my resized images to be cached.

Thanks

Comment: How are your images stored in your object? Please show the database relation code for your images.

Comment: 3dgoo, thanks for the reply. I was able to track down my answer on SSbits here: http://www.ssbits.com/snippets/2009/resizing-an-image-in-a-custom-img-tag/. I used the method name in the template (i.e., <img src="$CroppedImage(200,200).URL" alt="$Title" />)

Comment: Cool. Would you like to answer your own question with the solution and mark it as the accepted answer for anyone who comes across this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to track down the answer to my question on SSbits here: http://www.ssbits.com/snippets/2009/resizing-an-image-in-a-custom-img-tag/.

Instead of using `$Image` or `$File`, one has to use the method-name directly when in the context of the image. Eg. `$CroppedImage(200,200).URL` or `$SetWidth(80)`.

Comment: still true in SS 4.4